# write c# implementation of abstract class inline?

Tags: c#, android, mono, abstract-class

I found a great example of code written in java for the use of a timer / timertask classes...

I am currently turning this into c# for a 'Mono for Android' implementation, but having trouble with converting the inline implementation of the abstract class TimerTask

```
// Here's the original java code

private void resetMapChangeTimer()    
{        
mChangeDelayTimer.schedule(
new TimerTask()        
    {            
      @Override            
      public void run()            
      {                
        // Some code to run           
      }        
    }, longTenSeconds);    
}
```

When I implement this in c#, I would like to create an inherited class from TimerTask (abstract class) and the run method etc in-line without having to create a seperate class (extending TimerTask) as the java code above does.

Can anyone advise me on the c# syntax to create this abstract class inline instead of creating a seperate class just to inherit and implement TimerTask?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# doesn't support inline classes as in Java. You could define anonymous methods but not entire classes. So you will have to define a separate class that implements the abstract class.

Comment: Ah... OK, thanks for that. Wondered why I couldn't find documentation for this!  Thanks for the answer Darin.

Answer (score 5):

As Darin says, an anonymous function is the way to go here. You're only trying to specify one bit of behaviour, so just make the method accept an `Action` and then the caller can use an anonymous function (either an anonymous method or a lambda expression). The calling code would look like this:

```
changeDelayTimer.Schedule(() => {
    // Code to run
}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Or if you had a lot of code, you'd want to use a method, with a method group conversion:

```
changeDelayTimer.Schedule(MethodContainingCode, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

In Java I rarely find I want to do more than override a single method within an anonymous inner class anyway - so anonymous functions in C# almost always work just as well here.

When porting code from Java to C#, it's important not to try to preserve Java idioms - preserve the same *goals*, but porting to a .NET idiom, which in this case is using a delegate to represent a single piece of behaviour in an abstract way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use/extend existing Java classes you could implement a generic helper class:

```
class MyTimerTask: TimerTask
{
    private Action action;

    public MyTimerTask(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        if(action != null)
            action();
    }
}
```

You can then use anonymous methods:

```
mChangeDelayTimer.Schedule(new MyTimerTask(() =>
{
    //Do something

}), longTenSeconds);
```

To have the best C# experience in your project, you could further add an extension method. Create a public static class somewhere in your project:

```
public static class TimerHelper
{
    public static void Schedule(this DelayTimer /*or whatever your timer class is*/ timer, Action action, int delay)
    {
        if(timer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("timer"); //null check needed because this method is not really an instance method

        timer.Schedule(new MyTimerTask(action), delay);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following code: (The TimerHelper class must be "visible" to the executing context for the extension method to show up, therefore it is public)

```
mChangeDelayTimer.Schedule(() =>
{
    //Do something

}, longTenSeconds);
```